# Check client's TLS version in Node.js Https server

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, tls1.3

I'm making a web site using HTTPS. I want to check if the client is connected to my server with TLS 1.3 or 1.2(Or even 1.1 and 1.0), to prevent the client from accessing sensitive pages using TLS 1.2 or earlier (for security reasons). Will this be possible, as I cannot find any information of this?

Comment: What are you hosting the web site in? The answer is yes you probably can, but the implementation would depend on the platform.  Also not really a programming question.

Comment: A plain Node.js server as https.createServer function

Comment: Based on the documentation you get a [secureConnection](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#event-secureconnection) event with the TLSSocket and this socket has a method [getProtocol](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tlssocketgetprotocol) which returns what you need.

Comment: Do you want to just disallow any older protocol or do you want to issue a warning to the client. If you just want to disallow connections with older protocols you could set the [`minVersion`](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tlscreatesecurecontextoptions) during creating the https server. But be aware, that this will then just disallow for older clients to connect.